# Express: Replacing Require with Import in Code Files

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, commonjs, es6-modules

Using:

- express 4.17.1
- webpack 4.35.0

In Express, when converting code-files from CommonJS to ES Modules my typical mjs files looks like this:

```
import {default as express} from 'express';

var router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

router.use(function(req, res)
{
    // Get stuff from database and send something to web-browswer
});

export default router;
```

I'm fine with what's above, but I do miss using require() when importing these routes, because "what once took one line of code" now takes two lines of code for each route:

```
import { default as ordersRouter } from './routes/orders/index.mjs';
app.use('/orders/', ordersRouter);

import { default as invoicesRouter } from './routes/invoices/index.mjs';
app.use('/invoices/', invoicesRouter);
```

Using commonJS, the routes above would be concise one-liners:

```
app.use('/orders/', require('./routes/orders/index.js'));

app.use('/invoices/', require('./routes/invoices/index.js'));
```

Is there a one-line (require-like) way of using `import` to set up these routes?

Comment: The answer to your question is no.

Comment: I see. Yeah, I couldn't figure out a way around it. That's ok; its not too bad.